# How to perform stress testing/performance testing of UWP app that calls api

Tags: uwp, performance-testing, stress-testing, web-api-testing, redis-cache

I am looking for a way to do some performance testing of a UWP app that calls api's and uses radis cache.
The application will continuously perform action for 100 hours or more and i need to make sure the server response time is consistent and does not deteriorate the application's action response after running for so many hours at a stretch. By the way, there is no scenario of having multiple users here. I am still on the learning curve and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Microsoft built-in [profiling and performance tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/tools-for-profiling-and-performance) or 3rd-party profiler like [YourKit .NET Profiler](https://www.yourkit.com/.net/profiler/).

The end-user activity for the application can be simulated either in the application code itself or using 3rd-party tools like [Windows Application Driver](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver) or [Coded UI test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/test-uwp-app-with-coded-ui-test?view=vs-2019)

If you will need to simulate hundreds/thousands of applications communicating with the backend to load test the backend - you will need a load testing tool which supports protocol(s) used by your UWP application, check out [How to Run Performance Tests of Desktop Applications Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-desktop-applications-using-jmeter/) for example test setup

Answer (score 0):

You can add code that logs messages and events at certain points while your app runs. When you're testing your app, you can use profiling tools such as **Windows Performance Recorder** and **Windows Performance Analyzer** (both are included in the Windows Performance Toolkit) to create and view a report about your app's performance. UWP provides logging APIs, they are part of the `Windows.Foundation.Diagnostics` namespace. For more details, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/planning-and-measuring-performance#instrument-for-performance).

In addition, you can also analyze the performance of UWP apps using [Visual Studio diagnostic tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/profiling-feature-tour?view=vs-2019), e.g. CPU usage, memory leak, etc.